# How to prevent Cache Breakdown by nonexistent id?

Tags: java, database, caching, architecture

If one request with **nonexistent id**, the Cache doesn't get it, and the request will go through Database to query.

The nonexistent id requests will **all hit Database**, and if this is an attack, the cache cannot protect the Database.

**Soon the Database is down.**

So what can I do to prevent this type attack?

P.S. The database has too much data. And if one id just visit once, the **Null Object Cache** will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache an Optional in which you would save Optional.absent() in the first request if the response was empty. You have to invalidate this cache's Optional entity as soon as the associated Id is present in the database, or sooner if you are experiencing memory problems with a ever growing cache.

I like the guava's Cache and Optional classes as I think they address most of the possible issues and I'll use them in my example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;


public class OptionalCacheUsage {

  private static final Cache<Id, Optional<Entity>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
      .softValues()
      .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      .build();

  private static final Database db = Databases.getDatabase();

  Entity findEntity(final Id requestedId) throws ExecutionException, EntityNotFoundException {
    final Optional<Entity> optionalEntity = cache.get(requestedId, new Callable<Optional<Entity>>() {

      @Override public Optional<Entity> call() throws Exception {
        return Optional.fromNullable(db.getById(requestedId));
      }});
    if (optionalEntity.isPresent()) {
      return optionalEntity.get();
    } else {
      throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }
  }

  Id saveEntity(final Entity newEntity) {
    final Id savedId = db.save(newEntity);
    cache.invalidate(savedId);
    return savedId;
  }
}
```

Comment: But the database has too much data. And if one id just visit once, this solution will not work.

Comment: Yep, it won't. The best way to go, I think, is to limit the possible ids and then use this cache. Something like: I have 1000 entities today, so I'll limit the possible ids in the range 0, 2000. Anything outside that is considered nonexistent without consulting the db and you update that range's maximum value in a regular basis.